# Attach an Element to the DOM using Javascript - Can't target the correct DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to learn how to make a dynamic menu using Javascript.

The onload, the program will create a menu based on the h2 headings in the page.

If the body tag has an id = homePage the menu will insert at the top of the page, else it will insert a menu on the side of the page.

It was working, until I added a DIV wrapper(id = wrapper) around the content. Then it stopped working.

**Error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.**

I think it is because my if/else statement I am targeting the wrong element as the parent element. But I can't figure out how to target the DIV with the id = wrapper, and insert the menu before that elements firstChild.

I'm stuck!

If I comment out the DIV id=wrapper then it works.

HTML:

```
<body id ='notHomePage'>

  <!--<div id='wrapper'>-->
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>

    <h2>H2 Heading - 1</h2>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fermentum ullamcorper
    </p>

    <h2>H2 Heading - 2</h2>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fermentum ullamcorper
    </p>

    <h2>H2 Heading - 3</h2>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    </p>

 <!-- </div> -->

</body>
```

JS:

```
    if(pageIs == 'homePage'){
       
        //IF is homePage then load menu at top
        document.body.insertBefore(makeMenuDiv(), document.body.firstChild);
      

       } else {
        
        //ELSE load SIDE NAV
        document.body.insertBefore(makeSideNav(), document.body.firstChild);
       
 
       }//END IF
```

**CODE:**
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/acekicker77/pen/OQMgOX)

Comment: Just prints `"notHomePage"` for me. No error.

Comment: I recomend you to use Vue, React or Angular to build dynamic html

Comment: @LucasMarques that's not the kind of advice to give lightly, without knowing what OP actually needs. You don't throw libraries at the problem if there's no compelling reason to do so.

Comment: @LucasMarques: Seriously, no. Throwing libraries at everything is just unnecessary. Creating dynamic content is absolutely trivial these days.

Comment: `menu.setAttribute("id", "#mainMenu");` Why does the ID have a `#`? Either way, it's much cleaner to set the property. `menu.id = "mainMenu"`

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdLegr?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have finally got this to work. Here is the updated CodePen:

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/acekicker77/pen/yvJONw)

Two things that I had to change:

1) In my IF/ELSE statement I had to change how I was selecting the DOM elements because 1 page (homePage) NO wrapper div and the other page HAS a wrapper div:

```
        if (pageIs == 'homePage') {

        //IF is homePage then load menu at top
        document.body.insertBefore(makeMenuDiv(), document.body.childNodes[0]);

    } else {

        //NOT homePage then load side menu

        var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

        wrapper.insertBefore(makeMenuDiv(), wrapper.childNodes[0]);

    } //END IF
```

2) In my for loop, when attaching anchor tags to the front of h2 headings, I had to change how I was selecting the h2 headings, again, because the wrapper makes the `document.body.insertBefore` incorrect.

```
        //10. insert the anchor in the the document next to each <h2>
        //document.body.insertBefore(anchor, headings[i]);
        document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[i].insertBefore(anchor, document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[i].firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're needing to select the div, it should just be:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper')
```

So if I get what you're wanting, I think you should just have to:

```
if(pageIs == 'homePage'){

    //IF is homePage then load menu at top
    document.body.insertBefore(makeMenuDiv(),
        document.getElementById('wrapper').firstChild);                                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from

```
makeMenuUl()
```

The last function therein is

```
document.body.insertBefore(anchor, headings[i]);
```

And when you wrap everything in the body with a div, headings[i] no long a child of body- hence the error. Change that line to

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').insertBefore(anchor, headings[i]);
```

and it works for me.